# Importhtml with multiple pages

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import all the player data over the 4 pages on the following website:

https://sports.yahoo.com/nba/stats/individual/?sortStatId=ASSISTS_PER_GAME&selectedTable=0&qualified=FALSE

Is there a way to do this through googlesheet? I can get the first page to import without issue but cannot figure out how to get the subsequent pages to import!

Comment: How are you importing the table? Looks like the data is in the html as json format. If yo can parse that, you'll get the full table.

Comment: I was trying to do importhtml function in googlesheet as follows: =IMPORTHTML("https://sports.yahoo.com/nba/stats/individual/?sortStatId=POINTS_PER_GAME&selectedTable=0&qualified=FALSE", "table") but that only returns the first page of results.

Comment: I think it's not possible with importhtml. Other parts of the table are not displayed and can't be reached using url.

Comment: Ya we may need to write a google script that’ll parse that then.